# Drupal 6: Search index and custom content types

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6, indexing, content-type

Sorry, if question is too obvious — does Drupal 6 index nodes with custom content types, not only `story`, `page`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about `story` and `page` node types, they can even be deleted. So yes all nodes are indexed by default.